# Why did multiprocessing giving me EOFError : Ran out of Input Error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, eoferror

`videoPlayerThreading` is my own made library to basically making 2 class with each using threading to get and show frames. `objDect` is also my own library to basically return frame after object detection. I got `EOFError : Ran out of Input` error and from the traceback I think it is caused by the multiprocessing itself hence I don't post my library because it is so long. Can anyone help me with what is wrong with it? Thank you

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys

import videoPlayerThreading as vpt
from objDect import objDect as od


def main(videoSource):
    obd = od( videoSources = videoSource )
    
    getFrame = vpt.getFrames(videoSource).start()
    showFrame = vpt.showFrames(videoSource).start()

    while True:
        frame = getFrame.frame
        frame=Process(target=obd.predictYolo, args=(frame,)).start()
        showFrame.frame = frame

        if getFrame.doVideo == False or showFrame.doVideo == False:
            getFrame.stop()
            showFrame.stop()
            sys.exit()


if __name__=="__main__":
   main(0)
```

**Edit :**
Here is the show frames and get frames class it basically only get and show frame using threading.

```
class getFrames():
    def __init__(self, 
                 videoSource:Union[int,str]=0):
        self.stream = self.videoInit(videoSource)
        self.hasFrame, self.frame = self.stream.read()
        self.doVideo = True

    def videoInit(self,
                  videoSource:Union[int,str]):
        try:
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoSource)
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(f"Video source error: {e}")

        return cap

    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.getFrames, args=()).start()
        return self

    def getFrames(self):
        while self.doVideo:
            if not self.hasFrame:
                self.stop()
            else:
                (self.hasFrame, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

    def stop(self):
        self.doVideo = False
        self.stream.release()

class showFrames():
    def __init__(self, 
                 frame:cv2=None):
        self.frame = frame
        self.doVideo = True

    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.showFrame, args=()).start()
        return self

    def showFrame(self):
        while self.doVideo:
            cv2.imshow("Video", self.frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
                self.doVideo = False

    def stop(self):
        self.doVideo = False
```

Comment: Do you realize that with statement `frame=Process(target=obd.predictYolo, args=(frame,)).start()` that `frame` will be `None` because method `start` returns `None`?

Comment: @Booboo Sorry for the late reply. Is that so? then how can I get return from multiprocessing? Thank you

Comment: .Is module `videoPlayerThreading` something developed in-house? For now: In the statement `frame=Process(target=obd.predictYolo, args=(frame,)).start()`, is the return value `frame` something you expect `obd.predictYolo` to be returning? If so, look at class `multiprocessing.Pipe`, which returns two connections `conn1` and `conn2`. Pass `conn2` to `obd.predictYolo` as an argument. That method will return a value by issuing `conn2.send(frame)` and the main process will get the result with `frame = conn1.recv()`. Do not issue a `return` statement. (...more)

Comment: `conn1, conn2 = Pipe(); p = Process(target=obd.predictYolo, args=(frame, conn2)); p.start(); frame = conn1.recv(); p.join()`. Note: you can create the Pipe connections outside the loop before the `while True:` statement.

Comment: But in that `while True:` loop you are not doing multiprocessing because your main process is blocking waiting for the result from the process you just created. So only one process is running at a time. Nothing is gained by doing this.

Comment: But none of this may explain your EOFError. You should update your question with a stacktrace so we know where you get the error. Is this a `pickle` error trying to pass the frame to the new process?

Comment: @Booboo So how can I prevent my main process blocking it? I really I want my object detection to be able to do paralel processing to speed up time. Thanks. A moment I will share the traceback

Comment: You need to first post more details as to what your program is actually doing. We need to know what `getFrames`, `showFrames` and all the other methods do. Right now I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: @Booboo ok I will post it in a moment. Thanks for helping

Comment: So as I understand it, class `getFrames` starts a thread that continuously reads frames of a video setting `self.frame` while the main thread loops looking at that frame and does some unspecified processing on it. It may be processing the same frame multiple times if it loops quickly or it may miss a frame if it loops too slowly. Do I have that right? If I do, this is a very poor design. But you cannot get a return value from a `Process` instance the way you are invoking it. (more ...)

Comment: Besides, if you wrote the code under the assumption that you are blocking until you got a result back form `obd.predictYolo` (you weren't), then you weren't doing multiprocessing anyway since your main process was just waiting for the result to come back from `obd.predictYolo`. So what was the point in creating a new process? You should have just *called* `obd.predictYolo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can understand your program logic you need something like the following. Generator function `read_frames` (which may or may not need correction), reads the frames one by one yielding each frame. The main process creates a multiprocessing pool and passes each input frame to the multiprocessing pool to be processed by `obd.predictYolo` and sets `vpt.frame` with the returned frame. This continues until either there are no more frames to process or `showFrame.doVideo` is `False`. In short, I have done away with your `getFrames` class, which is useless here.

I do not have OpenCV installed and do not really know the package nor do I have your video file, so consider this a starting point for your further investigation.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
import sys

import videoPlayerThreading as vpt
from objDect import objDect as od

def read_frames(videoSource:Union[int,str]=0):
    try:
        stream = cv2.VideoCapture(videoSource)
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f"Video source error: {e}")
    while True:
        hasFrame, frame = stream.read()
        if not hasFrame:
            break
        yield frame


def main(videoSource):
    obd = od( videoSources = videoSource )
    showFrame = vpt.showFrames(videoSource).start()
    with Pool() as pool:
        for frame in pool.imap(obd.predictYolo, read_frames(videoSource)):
            showFrame.frame = frame
    
            if showFrame.doVideo is False:
                showFrame.stop()
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
   main(0)
```